# Swift dictionary ordering

Tags: swift

I have found an example of swift code and want to figure out: why item ordering is the same? If a dictionary stores associations between keys of the same type and values of the same type in an collection with **no defined ordering**.

```
import UIKit
var rank:Dictionary = [1: "First", 2: "Second", 3: "Third" ]
rank.updateValue("Fourth", forKey: 4)
rank[5] = "Fifth"

for i in rank {
    print(i)
}

print("\n")

var rank2:Dictionary = [2: "Second", 1: "First", 3: "Third" ]
rank2[5] = "Fifth"
rank2.updateValue("Fourth", forKey: 4)


for i in rank2 {
    print(i)
}
```

so input is:

```
(5, "Fifth")
(2, "Second")
(3, "Third")
(1, "First")
(4, "Fourth")


(5, "Fifth")
(2, "Second")
(3, "Third")
(1, "First")
(4, "Fourth")
```

Comment: A dictionary's order is unspecified, so it's perfectly valid for both to have the same order (and equally valid for them *not* to have the same order). It's also fairly unsurprising given that they have the same keys and number of key-value pairs.

Comment: Why not? "No defined ordering" does not mean "random ordering".

Comment: I didn't give an answer. I'm asking you a question, in the comments. It's a serious question. What's your answer to my question? You know what dictionary is unordered and that it has no defined order, so what do you care what the order happens to be?

Comment: @MagoNicolasPalacios the order is obviously NOT the same, your link does not really help - the ***only*** valid answer is that dictionaries don't have a defined order - period. Therefore whatever order you observe is only by "coincidence" / "randomness" / memory layout / whatever. You must not ever rely on the order of the values in a dictionary.

Comment: Therefore the question @matt asked is actually important - *if* you care about the order of the values, then your code is simply wrong since the order is random and nothing to be relied on.

Comment: Whatever order a given dictionary may appear to have is an implementation detail. No business of mine, no business of yours. Since you know that, why are you concerning yourself with it?

Answer (score 1):

Their order is the same by *chance*. Another run of the program may output something different. Another Swift version may output something different. Tomorrow it may output something different.

Here "undefined" means "don't rely on it". Now of course a particular dictionary has a particular order: you can iterate (key/value) pairs, and they will come in a specific order.

You can even tell that the order of a particular dictionary is *stable*: two iterations of the same dictionary will yield the results in the same order. And you can rely on this fact.

Answer (score 1):

you can not have it ordered.

> Iterating Over the Contents of a Dictionary Every dictionary is an
>   **unordered** collection of key-value pairs. You can iterate over a
>   dictionary using a for-in loop, decomposing each key-value pair into
>   the elements of a tuple.
>
> [...]
>
> The **order** of key-value pairs in a dictionary i**s stable between
>   mutations** but is **otherwise unpredictable**. If you need an ordered
>   collection of key-value pairs and don’t need the fast key lookup that
>   Dictionary provides, *see the KeyValuePairs type for an
>   alternative*.

see: https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/dictionary

> A dictionary stores associations between keys of the same type and
>   values of the same type in a collection with **no defined ordering**. Each
>   value is associated with a unique key, which acts as an identifier for
>   that value within the dictionary. Unlike items in an array, items in a
>   dictionary **do not have a specified order**. You use a dictionary when
>   you need to look up values based on their identifier, in much the same
>   way that a real-world dictionary is used to look up the definition for
>   a particular word.

see: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html

PS:
my guess is that the order depends on the hash of the key and this implementation can be changed over time.

Comment: While this is correct, it doesnt really satisfy the question. He could use/Implement a LinkedHashSet if one is available .. or something to this effect.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is

> why item ordering is the same?

The item ordering is the same because

1. you created both dictionaries in the same run of the program, and their sizes evolved in the same way, and
2. the Swift standard library doesn't yet implement per-instance seeding (but might someday).

Specifically, `Dictionary` is a hash table. A hash table stores its elements in an order influenced by the hash values of its elements. A Swift dictionary seeds the hash function with the value of the `_HashTable.hashSeed(for:scale:)` function. [Here's that function as of today:](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/b92c301e99f6aea71ebb079c3ef997c049521c36/stdlib/public/core/HashTable.swift#L93)

> ```
>   internal static func hashSeed(
>     for object: AnyObject,
>     scale: Int8
>   ) -> Int {
> #if false // FIXME: Enable per-instance seeding
>     // We generate a new hash seed whenever a new hash table is allocated and
>     // whenever an existing table is resized, so that we avoid certain copy
>     // operations becoming quadratic.  (For background details, see
>     // https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-3268)
>     //
>     // Note that we do reuse the existing seed when making copy-on-write copies
>     // so that we avoid breaking value semantics.
>     if Hasher._isDeterministic {
>       // When we're using deterministic hashing, the scale value as the seed is
>       // still allowed, and it covers most cases. (Unfortunately some operations
>       // that merge two similar-sized hash tables will still be quadratic.)
>       return Int(scale)
>     }
>     // Use the object address as the hash seed. This is cheaper than
>     // SystemRandomNumberGenerator, while it has the same practical effect.
>     // Addresses aren't entirely random, but that's not the goal here -- the
>     // 128-bit execution seed takes care of randomization. We only need to
>     // guarantee that no two tables with the same seed can coexist at the same
>     // time (apart from copy-on-write derivatives of the same table).
>     return unsafeBitCast(object, to: Int.self)
> #else
>     // Use per-capacity seeding for now.
>     return Int(scale)
> #endif
>   }
> ```

We can see that, at the moment, the hash seed depends only on `scale`. The `scale` is based on the dictionary's capacity. Since both of your hash tables evolved in the same way, they have the same capacity, so they have the same scale, so they have the same hash seed, so they use the same hash value for the same key.

We can also see that there has been some work toward making different hash tables use different seeds. If that change is made, then your program will **not**, usually, print the elements of the two dictionaries in the same order.

[The commented-out changes for per-instance hashing were only added a few days ago](https://github.com/apple/swift/commit/91c5a310fadb0ac37ecc0ff59f9d8ac33b724c85) (six days before I wrote this answer), so I wouldn't be surprised if they are enabled by the time Swift 5 is released.

Comment: Apple specifically announced at WWDC 2018 that this change was coming.

Comment: Do you recall which session had that announcement? I didn't find it in a quick review of the [Session 401: What's New in Swift transcript](https://asciiwwdc.com/2018/sessions/401).

Comment: It is in 401 all right..."The one caveat to watch out for is you might have some code where you're expecting that Hash values remain constant from different runs of your app or that if you iterate over a dictionary or a set you're going to get the elements in the same order. And this is no longer the case because of that random preprocess seed."

Comment: I interpret that as a warning about variance across multiple runs (“from different runs of your app”), not variance across multiple dictionaries within a single run. /shrug